# How to set alarm manager using date and time from Textview

Tags: android, date

I am converting a `timestamp` into `date and time` and setting the result on a `textview`.

For example `1443884578` is `Sat 3 October 2015 18:02`

I would like to set the above `date and time` into an `alarm manager`.After research i found a code that uses a date time picker.

```js
 public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v) {
        // Get the date from our datepicker
        int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = picker.getMonth();
        int year = picker.getYear();
        // Create a new calendar set to the date chosen
        // we set the time to midnight (i.e. the first minute of that day)
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        // Ask our service to set an alarm for that date, this activity talks to the client that talks to the service
        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);
        // Notify the user what they just did
        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: " + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

However its getting only the `date` and fires the `alarm` the minute the date occurs.

**PROBLEM:** I would like to get the `date` and `time` from my `textview` and skip this date time picker in the format i have. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String input = "Sat October 3 2015 18:02";   // Instead of String input = "Mon Feb 06 2015";

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = new Date();
// Changed the format to represent time of day
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(input);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    cal.setTime(date);
    //We haven't parsed the seconds from the original date so this will result 
    //in 18:02:00 - 10seconds.
    //For a correct calculation, you could parse the seconds as well
    //See SimpleDateFormat above, but you would have to provide the original date
    //with seconds as well
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -10);
    scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(cal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..so what do I set in  here instead of c -->scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);

Comment: No problem. I've modified the answer, hope it suites your need

Comment: The code in the try-catch block has an error , "set time(java.until.Date) in Calendar cannot be applied to (java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.until.Locale)

Comment: Ok, changed it again. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Nice work..it has worked..Thanks a bunch! But I was wondering if you overlooked the time part..you see the notification fires up when the date us reached at midnight.That's why there's the time bit..like Sat 3 October 2015 18:02.Any fix for that?

Comment: Edited my answer again :).

Comment: Sorry for being such a nag..but I am trying to make the alarm fire up 10 seconds before. I've tried adding -10000 to date and time but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks a lot ..i appreciate your help!!